# LdapCtxFactory because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, ldap, spring-ldap

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
   {
      httpSecurity
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/abc/**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
               .and()
               .csrf()
               .disable()
               .httpBasic();
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
   {
      auth.ldapAuthentication()
          .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
          .userSearchBase("ou=people")
          .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
          .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
          .groupSearchFilter("uniqueMember={0}")
          .contextSource()
          .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=concretepage,dc=com")
          .and()
          .passwordCompare()
          .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
          .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
   }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
      return passwordEncoder;
   }
```

Spring-Version: `SPRING_BOOT_VERSION = "2.6.6"`

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"

    api "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${JAVAX_SERVLET_VERSION}"

    compileOnly 'io.crnk:crnk-gen-java' 
    annotationProcessor 'io.crnk:crnk-gen-java'

    gradle.beforeProject { Project project ->
        project.with {
            apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
            dependencyManagement {
                imports {
                    mavenBom "io.crnk:crnk-bom:${CRNK_VERSION}"
                }
            }
        }
    }


    implementation platform("io.crnk:crnk-bom:${CRNK_VERSION}")
    annotationProcessor platform("io.crnk:crnk-bom:${CRNK_VERSION}")

    implementation "io.crnk:crnk-setup-spring-boot2"
    implementation "io.crnk:crnk-home"

    implementation "io.crnk:crnk-security"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:5.4.3'
    implementation 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk:4.0.14'

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}")
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.ssl.insecure=true
systemProp.http.ssl.allowall=true
systemProp.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="./cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit \
  --add-exports java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=spring.ldap.core
```

./gradlew --version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.2+8-86)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

The error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022.08.02 07:16:32.051 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication:830 - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in unnamed module @0x1d296da) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module @0x1d296da
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding `--add-exports java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED` instead of `--add-exports java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=spring.ldap.core` to your JVM arguments.

But a better solution would be to align all the dependency versions with the Spring Boot version you use (2.6.6):

- for `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security` either remove the version or set `2.6.6`
- `org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:5.4.3` is too old, should be at least version *5.6.2*. With this one chances are you won't need any explicit `--add-exports` at all.
- remove `org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core` - `org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap` brings it in automatically.

Comment: changed but same error ;-(

Comment: Worked in my case. Thanks a lot @dekkard.
--add-exports java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: This is a bad solution.   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76217255/139985 for thew correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked to add:

```
--add-opens=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED
```

instead of --add-exports

Answer (score 1):

This solution may be applicable to those who don't want to use `--add-exports` explicitly.

In my case, the issue was resolved after upgrading and using correct ldap core jar. Previously it was using *2.2.0.RELEASE* version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    <!-- version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version -->
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yup.  For Java 17 you need SpringBoot 3.x. Earlier versions of Spring do naughty things that involve accessing JDK internals.  Java 17 says to Spring "No dude ... don't do that".

Comment: Sometimes you can use Java 17 but not Spring 3, e.g. webapp on JBoss EAP 7.